# Using tf.saved_model.save() to save a model to GCS bucket from local

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to save a tensorflow model to a GCS bucket from my local machine(Jupyter Notebook). I do have the google cloud storage credentails json. How do I save the model to the bucket since Tensorflow supports gcs links in saved_model

I used it as follows:
`tf.saved_model.save(model, "gs://your_bucket")`

This throws the following error:

```
PermissionDeniedError: Error executing an HTTP request: HTTP response code 401 with body
```

```
Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object.",
```

How do I use my credentials json I have ?

Edit:
How to authenticate tf.saved_model.save() before calling it.
I have the following service account credentials as a json.

Comment: does [this](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#auth-cloud-implicit-python) help?

Comment: @AtefH. - Sorry but I tried that with ```os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]='credentials.json'
```
to no avail

Comment: Try to parse the credentials in your code, see [this](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#passing_code) part of the documentation

Comment: @AtefH. Thanks for that. But how to integrate that with the tensorflow ```tf.saved_model()```

Comment: You need to authenticate before calling `tf.saved_model()`, you can edit the question and include your code (remove sensitive data) and me or anyone could be able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Python Script
`os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]='credentials.json'`
and then
`model.save('gs://your_model_path_in_bucket')`
works

Comment: do you know if there's a parameter to "replace the entire folder"? or will the save command automatically do that?